# Xamarin iOS hide placeholder on click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, placeholder

I have a Xamarin iOS app, and it has textfields, so I want for my textfields to hide their placeholder on click not just when I start to input letters, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like below:

```
  string _placeHolderText = "Some Test Placeholder...";

  public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
  {
     base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

     var textView1 = new UITextField (new CGRect (0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 100)) {
        Placeholder = _placeHolderText,
        BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
     };
     textView1.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
     {
        textView1.Placeholder = string.Empty;
     };
     textView1.EditingDidEnd += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
     {
        textView1.Placeholder = _placeHolderText;
     };

     var textView2 = new UITextField (new CGRect (0, textView1.Frame.Bottom, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 100)) {
        Placeholder = _placeHolderText,
        BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
     };

     this.View.AddSubviews (textView1, textView2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you can set Placeholder text to an empty string when text field begins editing, and reset it to previous value if end editing and still empty.